# Is the intersection of a chain of covers also a cover?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of sets covering some set $X$, so $\bigcup_{F \in \mathcal{F}} F=X$.

Assume we take an infinite chain $\mathcal{X}$ of nested families $\mathcal{F}''\subset \mathcal{F}'\subset \mathcal{F}$ so for every $\mathcal{F}_1, \mathcal{F}_2 \in \mathcal{X}$ either $\mathcal{F}_1 \subset \mathcal{F}_2$ or the other way round, where inclusion is strict, such that we always have $\bigcup_{F \in \mathcal{F}'} F=X$ for all $\mathcal{F}' \in \mathcal{X}$.

Does it necessarily follows that $\bigcup_{F \in \bigcap_{\mathcal{F}' \in \mathcal{X}}} F=X$ or there is a counter example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an explicit counterexample, consider:

$$X = \Bbb N,\quad \mathcal F_n = \{S \subseteq \Bbb N: S \text{ finite}, |S| \ge n\}$$

Then $\bigcap_n F_n = \varnothing$.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong. It amounts to an illegal interchange of universal and existential quantifiers.